# Counting different date prices in booking calculator

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a booking cost calculator system and I took inspiration from previous questions here on Stackoverflow.

I actually have this table structure:

| Room_id | Start_date | End_date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-24 | 2021-08-06 | 115 |
| 1 | 2021-08-07 | 2021-08-28 | 145 |
| 1 | 2021-08-29 | 2021-09-12 | 65 |

where, according to different dates, there can be a different price.

I'm using this query:

```
$query = "SELECT   Room_id,
     SUM(Price * (1 + DATEDIFF(
          LEAST(End_date,   '$end_date' - INTERVAL 1 DAY),
       GREATEST(Start_date, '$start_date')
     ))) AS Total FROM     counter WHERE    Room_id = '1' AND (
          '$end_date' - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                       BETWEEN Start_date AND End_date
       OR '$start_date' BETWEEN Start_date AND End_date
     ) GROUP BY Room_id";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$rows[] = $row;
}
foreach($rows as $row)
{
$final_cost=$row['Total'];
}
```

And it works perfectly if date difference is between 2 different price period (example: from 2021-08-01 to 2021-08-10) giving me the correct total booking amount.

But if the booking period come across 3 different prices (example: from 2021-08-01 to 2021-08-31) it gives a totally wrong result.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

In the query you are missing the case that the row is "totally" included in the specified period: for for the period of from `2021-08-01` to `2021-08-31` the second row is not taken into account at all.

Try to use the following code.

```
$query = "
        SELECT
            room_id,
            SUM(price * ( 1 + Datediff( Least(end_date, '$end_date' - interval 1 day), Greatest( start_date, '$start_date') ) )) AS Total 
        FROM
            counter 
        WHERE  
            (
                ('$end_date' - interval 1 day) BETWEEN start_date AND end_date 
            ) 
            OR 
            (
                '$start_date' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date 
            )
            OR 
            (
                (start_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND ('$end_date' - interval 1 day)) 
                AND 
                (end_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND ('$end_date' - interval 1 day))
            )
        GROUP BY
            room_id
";
 
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row){
    $final_cost=$row['Total'];
}
```

I'm not sure that the code will exactly match your needs, as I'm not sure about the logic of the calculations, but I hope that it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help! We are halfway done with this code;

The only problem is that I'm getting x rows according to how many room_id I have in my db.

For example, I have 6 room_id so I'm getting 6 row result as total and when I print it, it always take the latest one instead of the corrected one.

Room_id 1 - 300
Room_id 2 - 400
Room_id 3 - 250
Room_id 4 - 500
Room_id 5 - 320
Room_id 6 - 200

If selected room was 4, system is always printing me the Room_id 6 as Total (the last value in the while loop.

Thanks